# How do you create this sort of query in SQL / Hibernate / GORM?

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

An initial implementation in GORM was something like

```
def stuff = Table.find { active = true }
```

Say we store different "revisions" and only one revision can be active at time.

The problem is when you create a new table that is initially not active. I want the active one, or the most recent one if none are active.

How would you create a query that says something like:
For each type of table (select distinct someId shared between revisions), get me the active revision, or, if there isn't one, get me the most recently created.

Is this problem beyond GORM's capabilities? What should I read up on?

Answer (score 0):

This won't always return the result with a single query, but I believe it will meet your requirements:

```
def stuff = Table.findByActive(true) ?: Table.first()
```

Comment: I think I may not have communicated the requirement as well as I could have.

Imagine these correspond to records in the database:
Table(id: 0, someId: 1, revision: 1, active: false)
Table(id: 1, someId: 1, revision: 2, active: true)
Table(id: 2, someId: 2, revision: 1, active: false)

There would also be a dateCreated in there, and I want my query to return rows with "id" of 1 and 2. 1 because it is active, and 2 because there are no active records with id 2 and theoretically it is the most recent.

Comment: @CodeMonkeyCharlie so it seems you want to return all active tables and the most recent (regardless of whether it is active), is that right?

Comment: only the most recent when there is no active one among all sharing someId. I ended up just doing two different queries and combining the results, which should work for now. I don't like it though.